# Where can I find the example data to create a Mosaic of NetCDF files?

Tags: geoserver, netcdf, mosaic

I am exploring the possibility of making a mosaic with NetCDF files. However, in the documentation pages (https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/netcdf/netcdf.html#mosaic-of-netcdf-files and https://geoserver.geosolutionsgroup.com/edu/en/multidim/mosaic_config/netcdf_mosaic.html#) it is discussed to edit files that should be available in the GeoServer folder root. I downloaded the data folder (https://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/) as well as GeoServer itself, but those data examples are not present.

[image]

Where can I find at least the indexer.xml and _auxiliary.xml discussed in https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/netcdf/netcdf.html#mosaic-of-netcdf-files?